# Is this a moth? How do these wings unfold?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

I'm having trouble understanding how these wings might work. Are they somehow folded or bent by 90 degrees so that part of the wing is vertical and part is horizontal to be more compact?

If so, how mechanically are they then made quickly more rigid and straight each time it enters flight, which should be fast to avoid being eaten?

Also, I'm guessing this is some kind of moth, but I have no idea. I don't really need an *exact* species ID, but some classification guidance would be appreciated!

This individual is about 2 cm long, and was seen recently (late July) in Taipei, on a hot, sunny day.

[image: Is this a moth? How do these wings unfold?]

[image: Is this a moth? How do these wings unfold?]

Comment: moths don't have 2 wings they have 4 wings, the forewings and hindwings are just being held apart in this image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_morphology_of_Lepidoptera

Comment: @John oh, that makes quite a bit of sense. Do you think this is in fact a moth? I've just guessed at that.

Comment: Yes definitely a moth, although I have no idea what the species is. You could ask for identification as a separate question. just be sure to include the last sentence of the post, where it is found is very helpful.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm still interested in how these wings would OPEN (be deployed) without bumping into each other. There must be some kind of rotation involved; perhaps the ones that are vertical in the photo would rotate forward first?

Comment: Not a moth. It is a skipper. Family Hesperiidae. https://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/5254

Comment: I'd be prepared to guess genus [Telicota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicota) also known as the Palm Darts.

Comment: @bob1 https://www.flickr.com/photos/77600294@N07/17632334189 :-) you're on to something http://dearlep.tw/species.html?namecode=345508, http://butterfliesvietnam.blogspot.com/2015/08/118-telicota-hoara-narrow-branded-palm.html

Comment: Uhoh, thanks to @KarlKjer for pointing in the right direction. I just put Hesperiidae into google and found the wikimedia page and browsed through for something similar to your photo, then did a bit more searching based on that.  I think the vietnam link you provided looks like a dead-ringer for your photo. Seems the ID is all around the wing patterns, so very hard to do to species from a couple of photos.

Comment: @bob1 well we don't have separate family- or genus-identification tags, so please feel to just write up something; I'm particularly interested in how the wings unfold and I think that part should be similar for many of them.

Comment: @uhoh - I'm no entomologist so I don't actually know, but it looks like the vertical wings are the fore-wings and as there are 4 wings (2 fore, 2 hind) each of the 4 is on its own joint (i.e. controlled at least semi-independently). The position is just fore folded up like a moth, hind folded flat

Comment: @bob1 I think it's maybe this one? http://dearlep.tw/species.html?namecode=345510 I see what you mean, I was so interested in photographing it that I didn't want to disturb it and make it fly :-)